# Any starter-kits/open source support center implementations out there?

Tags: asp.net, starter-kits

I'd like to implement a product support site in ASP.NET that will contain at least a forum and a knowledge base(FAQs). Could you recommend some good starting points?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Management Systems would do the job pretty quick if you need to deploy something fairly quickly with a minimal amount of work.

- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is a pretty popular and well supported content management system that would be able to handle a form and a knowledge base without too much difficulty. 
  [Here](http://www.dnncreative.com/Tutorials/DNNTutorialsforThirdPartyModules/OWSPart1/tabid/486/Default.aspx) is a tutorial for building a knowledge base site with DNN
- [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/default.aspx)is also a major CMS out there
- [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Microsoft_ASP.NET) is a list of additional Content Management Systems
- Found a Super Awesome CMS Browser that just makes things that much easier. You can sample different CMS's and the like and decide on the ones (yes you can choose multiple) you want. Along with a baked in direct publishing functionality I think its the cats meow. lol  
  [Scott Gutherine's introduction to Web Matrix](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx)